# Разбор dbf-файлов при помощи Python

Tags: python, struct, dbase, dbf

Хочу в одном из проектов использовать данные из [КЛАДР](http://www.gnivc.ru/inf_provision/classifiers_reference/kladr/). Поскольку данные придётся обновлять, хочется сделать инструмент, который позволит с минимальными усилиями выбирать из архива нужные данные и заливать их в БД (MySQL).

Читаю [спецификацию на dBase](http://www.dbase.com/Knowledgebase/INT/db7_file_fmt.htm) и [мануал по модулю Struct в Питоне](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/struct.html).

Залил базу в MS Access. Вижу, что в моей версии файла KLADR.DBF 7424 записи. В [dbf-описании формата](http://www.dbase.com/Knowledgebase/INT/db7_file_fmt.htm) вижу, что количество записей в файле - это 32-битное число (байты с 4 по 7).

```
import struct
data = open('KLADR.DBF', 'rb').read(24)
print(struct.unpack('>4h', data[4:7]))
```

Получаю:

```
struct.error: unpack requires a bytes object of length 8
```

Что я делаю не так? Какой вообще формат у 32-битного числа?

Comment: Э... А dbfpy чем не устроила? И ещё вроде парочка готовых библиотек есть.

Comment: Она под вторую ветку, насколько я понял. Под [третью ветку](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse&c=533&show=all) я ничего не вижу. Ну и все-таки хочется разобраться в магии чтения байтов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- КЛАДР "умер". Советую использовать вместо него базу [ФИАС](http://fias.nalog.ru/Public/DownloadPage.aspx) в XML формате.
- В вашем коде 3 ошибки:

  1. Код `data[4:7]` вернет только 3 байта, т.е. он не включает в себя 7'ой байт. А для int32 нужно 4 байта, т.е. правильно было бы писать `data[4:8]`
  2. В модуле [struct](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters) 32'х-битное беззнаковое целое число обозначается символом `I`
  3. Если верить приведенной выше ссылке, то в dbf используется [little-endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) порядок байтов. Соответственно, указывается это при помощи символа `<`.

  Т.е. конечный код должен быть:

  ```
  struct.unpack('<I', data[4:8])
  ```

Comment: Ок. Есть база ФИАС. И есть вопрос о вытаскивании данных из dbf-файлов при помощи Python 3.3.  И даже если принять как данность, что формат dbf тоже устарел, мне все равно хочется разобраться с модулем struct на реальном (описанном в примере) кейсе.

Comment: > мне все равно хочется разобраться с модулем struct на реальном (описанном в примере) кейсе

Это похвально, обновил ответ. Но есть кактус под названием КЛАДР я бы все равно не советовал :)

Comment: О! Спасибо!!!